# phpsessionclean.service causes long boot time in Debian Sid

Tags: boot, debian, login, cinnamon

I'm on a Debian Sid machine with Cinnamon as desktop manager.

Since a couple of days I get really long boot time. From switching on the computer to the login page no problem, but once here, to log in to the system, it can take also more than 3 minutes.

I gave `systemd-analyze blame` and it seems that `phpsessionclean.service` is the guilty:

```
matteo@debian:~$ systemd-analyze blame
     3min 7.981s phpsessionclean.service
         16.735s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
          6.529s postgresql@10-main.service
          1.781s keyboard-setup.service
```

I have no idea why it started to do that.

BTW: I can wait minutes before typing the password in the login page, then the session loads quickly, so it seems that this process take its time before the login.

`phpsessionclean.service` is ran by `php-common` and I really cannot uninstall this package since a lot of software I'm using depend on it.

Thanks for any hint

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this http://www.debianitalia.org/forum/varie/boot-molto-lento-su-debian-sid?page=1 (italian link, same OP) this issue is related to a recent change in how the linux kernel handles random numbers. Instead of giving a not-so-random number, which would be insecure, it awaits until the system generates enough entropy. Workarounds for this are: moving your mouse during the boot process (which will speed up entropy generation) or installing haveged (an entropy generator).

While the OP matteo already got his answer in the above link, I'm posting here to have an english version for others with the same issue.